# Replacing string with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, phpmailer, file-get-contents, str-replace

I'm trying to replace a string in a variable which got the content via file_get_contents().

```
$link_yes = "someText";
$link_no = "someText";
ob_start();
$mail_content = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. $user_file . $mail_file);
$link1 = array("###Text to replace###");
$link2 = array("###Text to replace###");
str_replace($link1, $link_yes, $mail_content);
str_replace($link2, $link_no, $mail_content);
$mail -> Body = $mail_content;
ob_end_clean();
```

I tried it without $link1 and $link2. So I pasted the string directly in the replace-function.

But it didn't work either.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove `array` with your `$link1` and `$link2`.

Comment: @Virb That is not the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_replace()` returns the amended string and you are not capturing that returned amended value.

Also unless you have more than one thing to replace you dont have to use an array, although that would not be an error

```
$link_yes = "someText";
$link_no = "someText";

ob_start();
$mail_content = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. $user_file . $mail_file);

$link1 = "###Text to replace###";
$link2 = "###Text to replace###";

$mail_content = str_replace($link1, $link_yes, $mail_content);
$mail_content = str_replace($link2, $link_no, $mail_content);


$mail -> Body = $mail_content;

ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Great answer, it's useful to know the difference between functions that alter a variable and those that do not. This is called "Passing by Reference" http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php. When exploring the documentation you can tell which functions support this by looking for the ampersand & symbol before the function argument. Having a better understanding of passing by reference is invaluable to budding PHP developers!

Comment: Wow, what a noob-fail^^..

I'm sorry.. but thanks for your fast answer!

Comment: @Florianb Dont panic, I do it all the time, and you will probably do it again. Just now hopefully like me, this will be the first thing that occurs to you when it happens again.

Comment: But now I have another problem:

$text= str_replace("###AUTHCODE-YES###", $link1, $text

This should replace the href-attribute with a new link. But php kills that href..

And the result at this place is:
<a>some text</a>

But it returns 1